# How to use LocalMediaDrmCallback for Widevine protected content in ExoPlayer

Tags: android, encryption, exoplayer, drm

I am trying to use LocalMediaDrmCallback for Widevine protected contents by explicitly providing decryption key but it does not work. It did work with Clearkey protected contents.

I know about HttpMediaDrmCallback but here I do not want to use license server url.

Answer (score 1):

This mechanism is mainly intended for ClearKey protected content and is not usually supported for full DRM systems like Widevine.

> A MediaDrmCallback that provides a fixed response to key requests. Provisioning is not supported. This implementation is primarily useful for providing locally stored keys to decrypt ClearKey protected content. It is not suitable for use with Widevine or PlayReady protected content.

(More info here: https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/drm/LocalMediaDrmCallback.html)

Widevine license responses are themselves encrypted by the Widevine license server and are designed to be only decrypted by the specific Widevine Client on a particular device.

Widevine does support persistent licenses, to allow for download and go use cases for example, in case this is what you are looking for.